# RESTful Batch Delete

Tags: rest, api, api-design

When batch deleting a resource. e.g. deleting all Orders that belong to Customer 99:

```
DELETE /customer/99/order
```

If there are defined business rules<sup>1</sup> that prevent Orders that meet specific criteria from being deleted. Such as:

- Orders that were made in the last 7 days can't be deleted.

---

*Given* customer 99 has orders that were made in the last 7 days.

*And* orders over 7 days old can't be deleted

*When* a client of the API makes a DELETE request to /customer/99/order

*Then* what should the HTTP response look like?

---

I'm not sure if even allowing this is a good idea. (i.e. allowing a partial success delete)

If it is a good idea, you would probably want to convey information such as:

- The resources that were deleted.
- The resources that were not deleted.
- The reason why a particular resource in the collection couldn't be
  deleted. If there are multiple reasons why a single resource couldn't
  be deleted this could get messy.

What status code would you even use for a response of this kind?

Is doing this even a good idea?

---

<sup>1: There could be any number of these 'rules' that prevent an individual Order from being deleted.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is doing this even a good idea?

So at the end of the day the batch deletion of orders on the back end is an implementation detail of the server. As far as the *client* is concerned it just asked you to delete a single resource, the 'orders' of customers 99. You can tell this by the fact that it has a single URL *customers/99/orders*

So the client is expecting that this resource is deleted or it isn't. A partial delete wouldn't make sense in this context, since the resource is either still there or it isn't still there.

The simplest solution is for the server to check the permissions of each order *first* and return a **403 Forbidden** is the client is forbidden from deleting all orders. In other words only start the deletion of each order if the server is sure that the client is actually able to delete them all.

But if you think this is going to be an issue where clients keep trying to delete orders that they don't have permission to delete due to business logic then a more long term solution is to reflect this in your URL scheme, since you clearly have two types of Orders now, ones the client can delete and ones the client cannot delete.

So something like

```
DELETE customer/99/expired_orders
```

which is only the orders old than 7 days and which the client can confidently delete would be the way to go. Remember your URL schema doesn't have to map 1 to 1 to your DB schema

If you really don't like a second URL being introduced you can use query strings, which are essentially a second URL but some think are clearer when expressing a subset of a particular resource

```
DELETE customer/99/orders?age=expired
```

Comment: Thanks, lots of good answers on this thread. But yours helped me the most. Thinking about the Orders resource as a singular as opposed to a collection of resources that either can or can't be deleted was very helpful. Using query params as a filter similar to how you would on a GET feels like the best way forward for me.

Answer (score 0):

"Is doing this even a good idea?"

No, not really.

With any batch operation you have to handle the case where it cant be completed because a single items fails for some reason.

The best way to do this is to fail the whole operation and provide a list of errored lines with a reason.

Essentially implementing a transaction, where the user can correct the errors and reattempt.

So your response body will look something like

```
{
   "success" : false,
   "error" : "unable to complete the deletion as some orders cant be deleted",
   "failedItems" : [ ("id":"aaaa", "reason" : "older than 7 days" }...]
}
```

The code you return depends on whether this is an exceptional event, that you want to cause an exception to be thrown (500) or if its a normal response where the client needs to read the response to see what to do next (200)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE /customer/99/order
```

This probably doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect. -- [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3.5).

REST includes a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) constraint.  Stated informally, it means that every API should interpret HTTP methods the same way that a boring document store / web site understands them.  Stated slightly differently: DELETE is of the "transfer of documents over a network" domain (see [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s)); modifying a batch of your domain entities is a side effect of the manipulation of the document.

The notion of a "partial success delete" really doesn't fit at all well with the semantics of DELETE as defined in HTTP.  You may or may not get into trouble with bespoke components that have learned your specific semantics out of band, but general purpose components are likely to get badly confused.

Expressed another way, the marginal benefits of using DELETE here vs a more appropriate method are unlikely to be all that significant, and the costs can be higher than you expect.

---

If, on the other hand, you were to use POST (see [Fielding 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)), you'd be on much safer ground.  POST semantics are deliberately vague, so general purpose components aren't going to be making extra assumptions about what a successful response means.

So you can perform whatever side effects on your back end are appropriate, and then return a 200 with a representation of the actions you took.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to approach this form from a different point of view

> Orders that were made in the last 7 days can't be deleted.

That's a fair requirement. Some countries are enforced by law to keep a copy of this sort of data for several years.<sup>1</sup>

###### But, what does DELETE mean?

We know about *physical* deletes and *logical* deletes. We also know that no universal rule or force in this universe and reality forces you to do only one of the two when your business is accessed via HTTP. The `DELETE` method is absolutely meaningless to your business. Leave alone Law.

So what to do?

###### Reality vs perception

Do you want all customer 99's orders deleted? Go ahead. Remove *physically* those you can and *logically* those you can't. Flag'em, move'em to another repository, make'em no longer available via Web API, etc. After all, `DELETE` is only meaningful for the most irrelevant actor of the system. An HTTP client.

Whatever forces you to retain old *orders* is backing the strategy of removing one and cataloguing the other.

In any case, the response to a `DELETE` is obviously `200 OK` if everything is *"deleted"* successfully.

If customers need to do some previous step before the _"delete" *(in order to fulfil some precondition)* then the response is likely to be `4xx`.

###### Observations

At this point, if you have found a blind spot in your requirements, you should stop solving a problem for which you have no answers. Maybe, you should ask the business experts first.

*What do you expect, as an end-user, of the web application? And what does the company expects? What does the company do (usually/legally) with all the 7d old orders?*

---

<sup>1: In my country, companies can be asked by the Tax Agency for documentation of the last 5 (fiscal) years</sup>